# What's the best alternative to using lists as elements in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with days as indexes, categories as columns, and each element is a set of items corresponding to each day.

I read that "keeping lists in a frame, while allowed, it not efficient at all": [corresponding pandas-dev issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3435#issuecomment-16870881)

I need to be able to build columnwise unions and intersections of these lists, and to use each of them in queries.

What would you suggest as an efficient alternative?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? Dictionaries & sets *may* be efficient for your use case.

Comment: I can’t be more specific with out more information but I’d use a multi index for your columns

Comment: I agree with @jpp, why are you requiring this to use Pandas?

Comment: I didn't require to use Pandas. I can't provide sample data, or I should build a fake dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your data looks like this

[image]

If you just melt the data to each row representing single item-category in a day, you can then use it any kind of union or intersection -

```
df1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars = 'Days', var_name = 'Category')
df1 = df1.set_index(['Days', 'Category'])['value'].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index().drop('level_2', axis=1)
df1.columns = ['Days', 'Category', 'Item']
```

The code above will turn the data into -

[image]

Which now can be easily used for any kind of operation

Comment: The reason I downvoted is this is inefficient. For repeated data, consider using Categoricals. The memory overhead for the dataframe can be large.

Comment: I agree, but I have a very large number of items that look as integers. I would surely be interested in something more efficient but the answer provided by @Aritesh is very practical for my needs.